# c++ - Way to know if Linux command exists before executing it

Tags: c++, linux, gzip

I'd like to write a function that generate gz file. The function will only be operational on `Linux` so I'd like to use `gzip` command (just execute external command).
So far I have this:

```
bool generate_gz( const String& path )
{
  bool res = false;

  // LINUX
#ifndef __WXMSW__

  if( !gzip_command_exists())
     cout << "cannot compress file. 'gzip' command is not available.\n";
  else
     res = (0 == execute_command(String::Format("gzip %s", path.c_str())));

  // WINDOWS
#else

  // do nothing - result will be false

#endif

  return res;
}

bool gzip_command_exists()
{
  // TBD
}
```

***Question***

Is there a way to implement `gzip_command_exists()`? If so, does it have to involve running ( or trying to run) `gzip` command?

Comment: There is a way, but there is no need. You have to check the result of the run anyway. Just try running the command and report any failure.

Comment: does the exit code from running the command tells me whether it existed and failed on process, or simply not existed? I'd like to distinguish between those failures.

Comment: Try `man execve` and see the errno description. (You probably should be using one of the `exec` family and not `system`).

Comment: fell free to tell me what exactly is not clear or not useful in this question to deserve a downvote. I'll be able to improve it that way.

Comment: I downvoted the question, because a little research would have told you about `zlib` and `gzopen` or simply that [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) can fail.

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch that wasn't the question though. I asked how to find out whether Linux command exists. `zlib`, `gzopen` & `system` (which I already use/aware of) do not solve/answer my question.

Comment: The point is that you do not need to check if `gzip` exist and you always need to check success of `system(3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is to execute via `system()` : `"which gzip"` and see the exit code of the system call:

> RETURN VALUE
>          The value returned is -1 on error (e.g.  fork(2) failed), and the return status of the command otherwise.  This latter return status
>   is in
>          the  format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the command will be WEXITSTATUS(status).  In case /bin/sh could not be
>   executed,
>          the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).

What to look for:

```
:~$ which gzip
/bin/gzip
:~$ echo $?
0
:~$ which gzip11
:~$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Interestingly, this did not work for me when run from a background process, e.g. a daemon.  In a foreground process, the result was zero; in a daemon, the result was -1.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to spawn an external command, you can use the [stat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) function to check if a file exists and if it is executable on a POSIX system.

It you do not want to hard code the path to gzip it is slightly more complicated. You will have to obtain the PATH environment variable, split it on colons, and then check each path for gzip. Again the name and format of path variables are POSIX specific. Check getenv function to read the path, and you could use strtok to split it.

It is questionable if it is worth checking, though, vs. just trying to run it and handling any errors.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to read the output of `/usr/bin/which gzip` (and you could also use it to compress on the fly by write-`popen`-ing a `gzip > file.gz` command). you could also have: `FILE* pgzipv = popen("gzip --version", "r");` and `fgets` the first line then `pclose`....

<sup>You could consider using `getenv("PATH")` then making a loop on it with an `access` test to each constructed path obtained by appending `/gzip` to each element in the `PATH`, etc... You could also `fork` then `execvp` using `gzip` `--version` with `stdout` and `stderr` suitably redirected, etc..</sup>

Notice that both [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) and [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) would fail when asked to execute a non-existing program (since they both [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) a [/bin/sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/sh.html) shell with `-c`). So you don't need to test the existence of `gzip`  and you always need to test the success of `system` or `popen` (which can fail for many reasons, see below for `fork` failure, and the documentation for other failures).

<sup>To be picky, checking that `gzip` exists is useless: it [the file `/bin/gzip`] could (unlikely) have been removed between your check -e.g. with `access` as below or with `popen` as above- and your later invocation of `system` or `popen`; so your first check for `gzip` don't bring anything.</sup>

On most Linux systems, `gzip` is generally available at `/bin/gzip` (and in practice `gzip` is always installed); 
this is required by the [file system hierarchy standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) (which says that if `gzip` is installed it should be at that file path). Then you could just use [access(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) e.g. with code like

```
#define GZIP_PATH "/bin/gzip" /* per FSH, see www.pathname.com/fhs */
if (access(GZIP_PATH, X_OK)) { perror(GZIP_PATH); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

At last, you don't need at all to fork a `gzip` process to *gzip*-compress a file. You could (and you should) simply **use a library like [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/)** (which is required according to the [Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libz.html) as `libz.so.1`); you want its `gzopen`, `gzwrite`, `gzprintf`, `gzputs`, `gzclose`  etc .... functions! That would be faster (no need to [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) any external process) and more reliable (no dependency on some external program like `gzip`; would work even if `fork` is not possible because limits have been reached - see [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_NPROC` and `ulimit` builtin of [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html))

See also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: thanks for the advice. seems like I add complexity to the implementation by using `zlib` instead. I'd like to understand what do I gain by using `zlib` instead of activating external command which 99% of the time will available?

Comment: With *zlib* (which is available and installed on every Linux system I heard of) you don't depend on external resources. So by using *zlib* you *lower* the complexity of your software!